How can I prepare for my new job? I have 2 weeks before I join
I'm re-joining corporate after 4 years and would like to prepare in whatever constructive way I can before the joining date. It's a BDM e-commerce role with a global brand/product manufacturer and is quite varied in scope. This is in Sydney, Australia.
Please share your tips on making a good first impression, and any questions I can ask my manager to build rapport and get to know his management style

Ask your manager-to-be what to study. Read up on whatever tools and processes s/he says you will be working with. Read up on the product you're going to be working on.  We can't tell you much more than that.

Thank you. I haven't reached out to the manager and will do that. I have been learning about their company, products and services as well as getting super familiar with the JD. Any tips on building rapport?
